# Maps v2 marker animation - fade in and out

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-animation, android-maps-v2

How would one fade in and out a [GoogleMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html) [marker](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html)?

This is how I add a marker to the Map:

```
    marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(point)
            .title(title)
            .snippet(text)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker))
    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Google Play services 4.0+ you can use `Marker.setAlpha` in conjunction with `Handler` that posts some `Runnable` every few milliseconds.

The code will be similar to my answer here [Drop marker slowly from top of screen to location on android map V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16604206/drop-marker-slowly-from-top-of-screen-to-location-on-android-map-v2/16607055#16607055). Just `setAlpha` instead of `setPosition` and you are on your way home.

Answer (score 7):

A much simpler and cleaner solution is to just use the standard `ObjectAnimator` which was introduced in Android SDK 11.

Fading in is literally a one-liner:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(marker, "alpha", 0f, 1f).setDuration(500).start();
```

Fading out requires a bit more code to properly remove the marker once the animation completes:

```
Animator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(marker, "alpha", 1f, 0f);
animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
        marker.remove();
    }
    @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {}
    @Override public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {}
    @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {}
});
animator.setDuration(500).start();
```

Comment: Tip: instead of using `Animator.AnimatorListener`, use `AnimatorListenerAdapter`, which allows you to only override `onAnimationEnd` and saves you of overriding 4 methods (3 of them empty).

Answer (score 0):

use this code for fade in and out

```
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 15));

            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure you understand my question. I want to fade in the marker as it is being added to the map. This just zooms in the map at a custom duration

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more complete solution specifically for **Fade In** when adding a marker. Something to note is the **requestNumber**. this is useful if you're loading items while moving the map. Just increment it on every service call or remove it if you don't need it.

```
public void fadeInMarker(Activity activity,final  GoogleMap map, final MarkerOptions markerOptions, final long duration,final int requestNumber){

        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (currentRequestNumber != requestNumber){
                    return;
                }

                markerOptions.alpha(0);
                final Marker marker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);
                final AccelerateInterpolator accelartor = new AccelerateInterpolator();

                final Long startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        float diff = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
                        float alpha = accelartor.getInterpolation(diff / duration);
                        if (alpha < 1) {
                            handler.postDelayed(this, 10);
                        }
                        else{
                            alpha = 1;
                        }

                        if (currentRequestNumber == requestNumber){
                            marker.setAlpha(alpha);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });


    }
```