# How can animated marker google map like shown in image in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, animation

How can I add this type of animation in google map marker in android?

If user tap icon for more than two second then marker clickable

How can set this in android?

[image]

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19753765/maps-v2-marker-animation-fade-in-and-out

Comment: Will marker always be at center of map?

Comment: yes marker has fix lantlong @Redman

Comment: If the marker is always in the center , then use this hack . Take a ImageView over the google map and show a gif as animation .

Comment: can you give me any example of this? thanks @Redman

Comment: Have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14883628/5110595)

Comment: Use circles (2) and adjust alpha and radius in animation - such as Handler-runnable every 10 millis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of the circle approach - first the recording followed by the code.

The radius growth is linear here but is obviously a different function in your example (it slows down as it expands) so you'll need to work with that.

[image]

```
public void pulseCircleTest() {

    // arbitrary point
    LatLng pt = new LatLng(39.171755, -86.510632);

    // move map to point of interest
    CameraPosition cp = CameraPosition.builder().target(pt).zoom(8.0F).build();
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cp));

    // create a circle and start animation
    int color = Color.BLUE;
    float initialRadius = 10;
    float maxRadius = 20000f;
    CircleOptions co = new CircleOptions().center(pt).radius(initialRadius).strokeColor(color).fillColor(color).strokeWidth(1.0f);
    Circle c = mMap.addCircle(co);
    Circle c2 = mMap.addCircle(co);

    final Handler h = new Handler();
    h.postDelayed(new Fader(h,c, initialRadius, maxRadius, Color.BLUE, co), 300);
    h.postDelayed(new Fader(h,c2, initialRadius, maxRadius, Color.BLUE, co), 750);
}

private class Fader implements Runnable {
    private float radius, initialRadius, maxRadius;
    private int baseColor, color, initialColor;
    private Handler h;
    private Circle c;
    private float radiusJump = 400;
    int numIncrements, alphaIncrement;
    private CircleOptions co;

    public Fader(Handler h, Circle c, float initialRadius, float maxRadius, int initialColor, CircleOptions co) {
        this.initialRadius = initialRadius;
        this.initialColor = initialColor;
        this.maxRadius = maxRadius;
        this.h = h;
        this.c = c;
        this.co = co;
        reset();
    }

    private void reset() {
        radius = initialRadius;
        this.color = initialColor;
        this.baseColor = initialColor;
        numIncrements = (int)((maxRadius - initialRadius) / radiusJump);
        alphaIncrement = 0x100 / numIncrements;
        if (alphaIncrement <= 0) alphaIncrement = 1;
    }

    public void run() {
        int alpha = Color.alpha(color);
        radius = radius + radiusJump;
        c.setRadius(radius);
        alpha -= alphaIncrement;
        color = Color.argb(alpha, Color.red(baseColor), Color.green(baseColor), Color.blue(baseColor));
        c.setFillColor(color);
        c.setStrokeColor(color);

        if (radius < maxRadius) {
            h.postDelayed(this, 25);
        } else {
            c.remove();
            reset();
            c = mMap.addCircle(co);
            h.postDelayed(this, 2000);
        }

       //done
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** This is not the right solution but just a hack to work around .

In your layout take Google map fragment and an `ImageView` in center

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_customerlocation" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

now take a gif image of the animation you want and load the gif image into `ImageView` using `Glide` or something else

If you want to know the location if user moves the map you can use `onCameraIdle()` method to get the new location

```
 @Override
  public void onCameraIdle() {
    if (mGoogleMap != null ) {
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition();
        LatLng latLng = cameraPosition.target;
     }
  }
```