# How to calculate the area of possible location when the GPS is inaccurate (as in Google Maps)

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location, android-gps

In Google Maps, the blue dot shows you where you are on the map. When Google Maps isn’t sure about your location, you’ll see a semi-transparent blue circle around the blue dot. You might be anywhere within the light blue circle. The smaller the circle, the more certain the app is about your location.

Now, my question is how to achieve the same behavior in another app. Does Google Maps use a feature of the location-determining hardware or it is only software? How would one achieve something similar?

Comment: @Andy, can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on which API - but for example the `Location` class provides a [getAccuracy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location#getAccuracy()) units in meters.

Conveys accuracy as 1 stddev of error.

So the simplest approach is to draw a circle with that location and radius - and use a gradient fill.  Here's an example of an animated (pulsing) circle: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52323267/2711811