# Google maps bounce-in animation for markers on show, on Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, animation

Is there any way to animate the markers showing on the map? My markers are being shown as I scroll the through the map (asynchronously). For now, they appear static on the map. I would like to make them fall in from above while fading in. Is there any way to add this option to `MarkerOptions`? something like this:

```
static final LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(-37.813, 144.962);
Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                          .position(MELBOURNE)
                          .alpha(0.7f))
                          .animateShow(MarkerOptions.BOUNCE_IN); //this is what I wish for
```

THANKS!

Comment: @SimplePlan none of the links talking about show animations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple answer by getting the location x , y coordinates on the mapView and starting animation fro y = 0 till the location coordinates

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16607055/2294985